# Laravel: make page available without authorization

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project on Laravel with a big amount of pages. I want to make one of my pages to be available even for users who are not authorized. It's like the 'Login' page. For example, to let everybody freely see the content of page "mysite.com/hello" (it's not the 'Login' page, but everybody who has this link can see the content of this page).
Can you please tell me what should I do with route/controller to show this page without authorization?

Comment: Most probably, that depends on the way you've developed your authentication

Comment: By default every page is public. You can protect them later using middleware or other techniques

Comment: Seeing a page without logging in is the default behaviour before adding middleware isn't it?

Comment: Don't protect it with an auth middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everybody!
I've solved my problem. In my Controller class I've found this line:

```
$this->middleware('admin')
```

So, I've added the except to it:

```
->except('hello')
```

It works.

Answer (score 4):

in your `web.php`

```
 Route::get('/hello','MyController@hello');   
 Route::get('/hello2','MyController@hello2');
 Route::get('/hi','MyController@hi');
```

in your `MyController.php`

```
  class MyController extends Controller
  {

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('auth',['except'=>['hello','hello2']]);
   }

   // this function do not use auth middleware
   public function hello(){
       return response()->json(['hello'=>'hello page for all']);
   }

   public function hello2(){
       return response()->json(['hello2'=>'hello2 page for all']);
   }

   // this function use auth middleware
   public function hi(){

        // check if user is logged in ?

       if(Auth::check()){
           return response()->json(['hi'=>'hi page for logged user in only']);
       }else{
           // user is not logged in 
           return response()->json(['hi'=>'please login to see content']);
           // redirect back to login 

           // return redirect('/login');
       }
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your controller file which had the function

Let say function is `hello();`

Then in your class constructor add the `except` function to hello

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except("hello");
}
```

Check laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score 0):

As the guys in the comments mentioned, every page by default is public unless you protect the route using a middleware, so for your page, you can do it just in the routes as long as it just returns a view like this:

```
Route::get('/hello', function() {
    return view('index'); // the index.blade.php should exist inside resources/views directory
});
```

Make sure that you don't put this route in any group, just as it is within your `web.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how the route is defined to access your page. By default it will be accessible to everyone.

You will probably see a route like:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->get('/pages/{slug}')->uses('PageController@show');
```

You can then for instance have some specific slugs which are unprotected or not available to logged-in users:

```
Route::get('/pages/for-everyone')->uses('PageController@show');
Route::middleware('guest')->get('/pages/not-for-logged-in')->uses('PageController@show');
Route::middleware('auth')->get('/pages/{slug}')->uses('PageController@show');
```

You middlewares may be defined in the controller too, in which case you need to unprotect per controller method instead of per route.